# uid is not taking

Tags: database

I'm getting uid by $account->uid on rules when I wrote a query by using this id it returns 0 rows.
Below is the code that i'm writing on rules

```
$uid=$account->uid;
$sql="select * from profile where uid=:uid";
$args = array(':uid' => $uid);
$row = db_query($sql, $args)->rowCount();
echo $row;
```

the output is 0. uid is there on both tables
please help me why this is happening.

Comment: Which version of Drupal are you using, and are you sure that there is table named 'profile'?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [`DatabaseStatementInterface::rowCount`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/DatabaseStatementInterface%3A%3ArowCount/7) states:

> Returns the number of rows affected by the last SQL statement.
>
> Return value
>
> The number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE
>   statement executed.

Notably, "SELECT" isn't included in there, so may not be reliable to use with selections.

Assuming `$account` is a valid user object, you may find you have a query result if you try something like:

```
// Get query result using db_select
$result = db_select('profile', 'p')
            ->fields('p')
            ->condition('uid', $account->uid)
            ->range(0,1)
            ->execute()
            ->fetchObject();
drupal_set_message('<pre>'.var_export($result,1).'</pre>');
```

It might just be the missing curly braces around the table name (profile versus {profile}).

Lastly, you might also be interested in [`profile2_load_by_user($account, 'main')`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!profile2!profile2.module/function/profile2_load_by_user/7).